# Prevent zombie.js from loading only external resources

Tags: javascript, testing, express, zombie.js

I am using zombie.js to load a page from a local express server during a test. Unfortunately, there is a script element which calls out to Google Analytics. I would like to block this external script (gracefully) without preventing other (local) scripts from loading, if possible.

I know that `{ runScripts : false }` is available with calls to `browser.visit()`. However, that refuses to load any and all scripts on the page, not just those living on other hosts. Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use the [resources](https://github.com/assaf/zombie/blob/master/src/zombie/resources.coffee) object.

You can set certain requests to give specific responses if you don't want the request to actually go through. You'd do the following to make google analytics return an empty document:

```
browser.resources.mock('http://google.com/url/to/analytics.js',{});
```

Note that you have to provide the exact URL that you want to mock, there is no way to mock a partial URL such as a domain name.

Comment: It seems to me the `resources.mock` method is no longer present in zombie 4.x. See https://github.com/assaf/zombie/blob/master/src/resources.js

Answer (score 8):

Since [zombie 3.1](https://github.com/assaf/zombie/blob/9fb0d3fa98d35f45024c76e2e856238e1c005aa5/CHANGELOG.md#version-310-2015-03-15), the `browser.resources.mock` method is gone. The alternative is to use [`nock`](https://github.com/pgte/nock) library:

```
var nock = require('nock')

nock('http://www.google-analytics.com')
  .get('/analytics.js')
  .times(Math.Infinity)
  .reply(200, '{}')

var Browser = require('zombie')
var browser = new Browser()
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this would work for you? It loops through all resources and "aborts" the ones that should be ignored.

```
const Fetch = require('zombie/lib/fetch');

const ignoredResources = [
  'google-analytics.com'
];

browser.pipeline.addHandler((browser, request) => {
  let doAbort = false;

  ignoredResources.forEach(domain => {
    if (request.url.includes(domain)) {
      doAbort = true;
    }
  });

  if (doAbort) {
    return new Fetch.Response('', { status: 200 });
  }
});
```