# Zombie.js unable to access dataset property of DOM elements

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, mocha.js, integration-testing, zombie.js

I have a page which contains a rich-text editor. I used CKEditor for this. You pass it a div element and it loads the editor into that element.

Now I wanted to write integration tests for that page. I am using zombie.js with version 4.2.1 (old, I know, but I'm stuck with it) for that purpose. However, I get an error just trying to load the page. The problem apparently happens while trying to load editor into the div element. This is the relevant output:

```
[some other resources loading]
  zombie GET http://localhost:10003/js/lib/ckeditor.js => 200 +0ms
  zombie GET http://localhost:10003/js/pages/categories/init.js => 200 +0ms
  zombie http://localhost:10003/js/lib/ckeditor.js:6623
                e.dataset.ckeFiller = true;
                                    ^

TypeError: Cannot set property 'ckeFiller' of undefined
    at au (http://localhost:10003/js/lib/ckeditor.js:6623:37)
    at Module.<anonymous> (http://localhost:10003/js/lib/ckeditor.js:7326:24)
    at n (http://localhost:10003/js/lib/ckeditor.js:57:22)
    at http://localhost:10003/js/lib/ckeditor.js:100:20
    at http://localhost:10003/js/lib/ckeditor.js:101:10
    at t (http://localhost:10003/js/lib/ckeditor.js:47:258)
    at http://localhost:10003/js/lib/ckeditor.js:48:7
    at Script.runInContext (vm.js:133:20)
    at Object.runInContext (vm.js:311:6)
    at window._evaluate (/home/laura/Projekte/fricke/hybristools/node_modules/zombie/lib/document.js:253:75)
    in http://localhost:10003/categories +68ms
Debug-Output hier:
undefined
{ http://localhost:10003/js/lib/ckeditor.js:6623
                e.dataset.ckeFiller = true;
                                    ^

TypeError: Cannot set property 'ckeFiller' of undefined
    at au (http://localhost:10003/js/lib/ckeditor.js:6623:37)
    at Module.<anonymous> (http://localhost:10003/js/lib/ckeditor.js:7326:24)
    at n (http://localhost:10003/js/lib/ckeditor.js:57:22)
    at http://localhost:10003/js/lib/ckeditor.js:100:20
    at http://localhost:10003/js/lib/ckeditor.js:101:10
    at t (http://localhost:10003/js/lib/ckeditor.js:47:258)
    at http://localhost:10003/js/lib/ckeditor.js:48:7
    at Script.runInContext (vm.js:133:20)
    at Object.runInContext (vm.js:311:6)
    at window._evaluate (/home/laura/Projekte/fricke/hybristools/node_modules/zombie/lib/document.js:253:75)
    in http://localhost:10003/categories
  cause:
   http://localhost:10003/js/lib/ckeditor.js:6623
                   e.dataset.ckeFiller = true;
                                       ^

   TypeError: Cannot set property 'ckeFiller' of undefined
       at au (http://localhost:10003/js/lib/ckeditor.js:6623:37)
       at Module.<anonymous> (http://localhost:10003/js/lib/ckeditor.js:7326:24)
       at n (http://localhost:10003/js/lib/ckeditor.js:57:22)
       at http://localhost:10003/js/lib/ckeditor.js:100:20
       at http://localhost:10003/js/lib/ckeditor.js:101:10
       at t (http://localhost:10003/js/lib/ckeditor.js:47:258)
       at http://localhost:10003/js/lib/ckeditor.js:48:7
       at Script.runInContext (vm.js:133:20)
       at Object.runInContext (vm.js:311:6)
       at window._evaluate (/home/laura/Projekte/fricke/hybristools/node_modules/zombie/lib/document.js:253:75)
       in http://localhost:10003/categories,
  isOperational: true }
```

I know that the error is not related to CKEditor because I tried it with another rich-text editor, which gave me the exact same error (only the property name was different).

The error apparently happens while trying to set the value of the HTML property "data-cke-filler" of a br element. This is the element:

[image]

That element is inserted into the editor at the time of creation, it represents the content of the editor, which is empty at the beginning.

I tried to use zombies debugging capabilites, however, as the error occurs while the site loads I don't really get a chance to output anything useful. As far as I am aware, zombie.js should be able to handle loading this page.

So my question is:
What is causing this error and how can I fix it?

Let me know if you need more information.

Thanks.

**Edit:**

Here is the code where I load the page (it's written in CoffeeScript):

```
require 'should'
Browser = require '../../support/browser'

describe 'editor page', ->

  browser = new Browser({debug: true})

  before (done) ->
    browser.debug()
    browser.visitLoggedIn('/', {name: 'tester', password: 'secret'})
      .then (done) ->
        browser.visitPage '/editor' # this is what doesn't work
      .then (done) ->
        console.log 'page loaded'
      .catch (error) ->
        console.error error

  it 'things should appear', ->
    ...
```

The `visitLoggedIn` method is a custom method that just creates necessary cookies for browsing the application as an authenticated user and visits the page using `visitPage`. `visitPage` uses zombies `visit` method. These work fine in all the other integration tests of this application.

---

**Edit 2:**
So I managed to "mock" CKEdtor using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30627095/9038691). This isn't exactly what I wanted, but I decided to try to work with this for now. However, now I get the exact same error! This time the error is thrown inside my own code:

```
# These are two functions that are run shortly after inserting the editor into the page,
# so basically while the page is still loading. 
getLanguageChoice: -> # This one is executed first
    document.getElementById('language').value

  getMandantChoice: -> # This one second
    document.getElementById('shopClient').dataset.name # The error is thrown here
```

This is the exact error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at Object.CategoriesView.getMandantChoice (http://localhost:10003/js/pages/categories/view.js:49:59)
    at http://localhost:10003/js/pages/categories/app.js:22:97
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

This doesn't make any sense to me. Does this mean that zombie somehow can't access the values of data-* attributes? Maybe someone is knowledgeable about zombie and can provide further insight?

Comment: Can you share the relevant part of your code?

Comment: Which line is your code crashing at?

Comment: @LajosArpad It crashes at the line with the call to `browser.visitPage('/editor')`, which just is a wrapper for the method `browser.visit()` provided by zombie.js. That line produces the error output I posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After further looking around with the new insights I gained, I found [this ticket](https://github.com/assaf/zombie/issues/801) on the Github page of the project. It looks like the dataset property is not implemented in an underlying library in the used version. As I am not able to upgrade, it's just not possible to load the page like it is...

To work around this, I will refactor my code to not use the data-* property. This is luckily not tied to too much work in my case.